# functional tests in Silex for language switch

Tags: symfony1, phpunit, silex

The problem is that in the tests the langauge wont switch, on the website is does well.
So the tests fail.

I have this routing:

```
$app->before(function () use ($app) {

        if ($locale = $app['request']->get('locale')) {
            $app['locale'] = $locale;
        }
    ...
    }); 
$app->get('/{locale}/index', function () use ($app) {
            return $app['twig']->render('index.twig');
    })->assert('locale',implode('|', $app['languages']));

$app->get('/{locale}', function () use ($app) {
            return  $app->redirect("/".$app['locale']."/index");
    })->assert('locale',implode('|', $app['languages']));
```

The test is so:

```
public function testLanguageRoutes(){
    $client = $this->createClient();
$client->followRedirects();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/de');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Kopf")')->count() > 0);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/de/index');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Kopf")')->count() > 0);
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/fr');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
    //TODO not working, still returns de should return fr
    var_dump($crawler->text());
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Pied")')->count() > 0);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/aa');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isNotFound());
}
```

Here the switch to french wont work, *$crawler->text()* still shows the german text.

Do I have to create one Test for each language?
That wont test the langauge switch really, in my opinion.

What is common way to test a scenario like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the way your translation code works. If the language that is used for translation is tied to your translator, then it may not change on the second request.

This is one of the limitations of pimple, you cannot reset the container.

You could try working around it by insulating the requests. You do this by loading the Symfony `Process` component (just make sure the autoloader can find it) and calling `insulate(true)` on your `BrowserKit Client` instance.

Comment: What do you mean by: "tied to your translator"?
actually i just register the TranslationServiceProvider and use:
$app['locale'] = $locale;

pretty much the same as the example in the docs

Comment: That's exactly the issue. The translator (if you look at the TranslationServiceProvider code) is initialized with the `locale` parameter, which is then used for the further existence of the container. I will open a ticket on the silex tracker, but I cannot promise that we will find a fix for it.

Comment: i see, alright i adjust my tests for now, thanks a lot for the info